# Certain games running extremely slowly when my other monitor is turned off

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-geforce, opengl

I'm running a laptop (MacBook Pro 2010, nVidia 330m, Boot Camped to Windows 10) hooked up to an external display (actually a Vizio M220MV television) via HDMI.

Lately, I've noticed a bizarre problem with certain OpenGL-based games (only certain ones though): when my laptop's built-in display is turned off (Windows' "multiple displays" setting is set to "display only on 2"), those games take a massive performance hit. Audio is fine, and CPU usage appears normal, but framerate drops to the single digits (if that) and controls become completely unresponsive.

This issue *only* occurs if the computer is set to output to the TV *and only to the TV*. If it's set to "duplicate these displays", "extend these displays", or "display only on 1", or if the TV is turned off or unplugged, the games run fine.

I've noticed this issue in the following games/programs:

- The Binding Of Isaac: Rebirth - issue only occurs when in windowed mode, fullscreen works fine.
- Jamestown
- Project64 (Glide64 plugin) - issue only occurs when "Limit FPS" is turned *off*.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this issue? Turning my laptop's display back on works, but I'm mainly curious as to why this is happening in the first place.

Comment: Have you played with changing your "Multi-display/Mixed-GPU Acceleration" settings within "Manage 3D Settings" in your NVIDIA control panel?

Comment: Yes, none of them help. Also tried vSync and triple buffering.

Comment: Probably sendIng you on a wild goose chase but found these which may be part of the problem. It sounds like your laptop also has an inbuilt Intel graphics card which auto switches. It may be that frames tank because it's no longer using the discrete card.  https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202053 and one here http://www.cnet.com/news/fix-poor-retina-macbook-pro-graphics-performance/ and here https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202043 sorry if I'm sending you in the wrong direction.